# pandas help: map and match tab delimted strings in a column and print into new column

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `data` which have last column containing a bunch of sting and digits and i have one more dataframe `info` where those sting and digits means, i want to map user input(item) with `info` and match, print and count how many of them present in the last column in `data` and prioritize the dataframe `data` based on numbder of match

```
import pandas

#data

data = {'id': [123, 456, 789, 1122, 3344],
            'Name': ['abc', 'def', 'hij', 'klm', 'nop'],
            'MP-ID': ['MP:001|MP:0085|MP:0985', 'MP:005|MP:0258', 'MP:025|MP:5890', 'MP:0589|MP:02546', 'MP:08597|MP:001|MP:005']}

test_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

#info

info = {'MP-ID': ['MP:001', 'MP:002', 'MP:003', 'MP:004', 'MP:005'], 'Item': ['apple', 'orange', 'grapes', 'bannan', 'mango']}

test_info = pd.DataFrame(info)
```

user input exmaple:

```
run.py apple mango
```

desired output:

```
id Name                   MP-ID match   count
3344  nop  MP:08597|MP:001|MP:005   MP:001|MP:005   2
123  abc  MP:001|MP:0085|MP:0985    MP:001  1
456  def          MP:005|MP:0258    MP:005  1
789  hij          MP:025|MP:5890        0
1122  klm        MP:0589|MP:02546       0
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get all arguments to variable `vars`, filter `MP-ID` by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and extract them by [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html), last use [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
import sys

vals = sys.argv[1:]

#vals = ['apple','mango']
s = test_info.loc[test_info['Item'].isin(vals), 'MP-ID']

test_data['MP-ID match'] = test_data['MP-ID'].str.findall('|'.join(s)).str.join('|')
test_data['count'] = test_data['MP-ID match'].str.count('MP')
test_data = test_data.sort_values('count', ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
print (test_data)
     id Name                   MP-ID    MP-ID match  count
0  3344  nop  MP:08597|MP:001|MP:005  MP:001|MP:005      2
1   123  abc  MP:001|MP:0085|MP:0985         MP:001      1
2   456  def          MP:005|MP:0258         MP:005      1
3   789  hij          MP:025|MP:5890                     0
4  1122  klm        MP:0589|MP:02546                     0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it is almost there, need a small change in the output, how to add ```drop duplicate``` for the "MP-ID match" column before counting? because there are duplicates in the "MP-ID" column

Comment: @Luffy - change `.str.findall('|'.join(s)).str.join('|')` to `.str.findall('|'.join(s)).apply(set).str.join('|')`